# Symfony still slow in Docker with WSL2

Tags: php, docker, symfony, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**TL;DR:**
14 months after I read about WSL2 coming for Windows (and Docker) I tried Symfony 5 and it is still slow as chocolate balls.

Back in Q1 2020 I read about Symfony and Docker being very slow in an easy set-up environment. We tried and tried, but to no avail: we couldn't get Symfony sub 4.000ms no matter how hard we tried. One of the solutions obviously was moving the vendor folder outside the bind-mount managed by Docker and Window (which is accessible through explorer.exe) and the same goes for the var directory (for logs and cache).

It now being Q2 2021, well over a year later, I rotate between PHP and .NET but still I wanted to give it a try. I downloaded the freshest version of Docker Desktop for Windows I could find, together with Hyper-V and WSL2 support. I installed the support drivers from Microsoft and I was set to begin.

A small hour later, after looking up some data on how Docker actually worked again, I quickly deployed a PHP 7.4, NGINX, PostgreSQL, MongoDB and Redis container/stack and it all worked fluently with a simple phpinfo() and some random calls to the aforementioned databases.

I installed a brand new Symfony 5 and to my surprise I still found that the problem persisted. No connection to the database has even been made and still it failed to function. Naturally I simplified my stack back to a PHP 7.4 and NGINX stack, hoping somewhere I eagerly lost my way. Unfortunately I was met by a rude awakening - it still sucks chocolate balls.

**My setup**

```
# ./docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
    networks:
      - symfony

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - symfony

networks:
  symfony:
```

PHP-FPM

```
# ./php-fpm/Dockerfile
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
RUN apk --update --no-cache add git nano
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD php-fpm
EXPOSE 9000
```

NGINX

```
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD ["nginx"]
EXPOSE 80
```

As you can ascertain from my example above I have a `src` folder which plain and simply holds a `symfony new src --full` install with all the bells and whistles provided by the basic installation - nothing more.

The only solution I could find to make my installation fly was to do the following inside the `php-fpm` container:

```
cd /var/www
rm -rf var/
mv vendor ..
ln -s /vendor vendor/
mkdir /var-symfony
chmod 777 /var-symfony
ln -s /var-symfony var/
```

While I can simply put this in a Dockerfile or the compose YAML it begs the question: why the flippin' freck is this slow as fluid doo-doo? I thought they might've fixed it after at least a year of tons of complaints.

I also found the `networks` option which is reflected in my YAML. That didn't solve anything either. Maybe it'll lower the TCP connection due to it being TCP and not directly onto a socket but I have yet to try and bench that.

I read up on some stuff creating a volume using docker, which somewhat solves the problem but not entirely. It still feels like patchwork for something that should work out-of-the-box.

Does anyone have a real world usecase where this actually works?

Comment: From a quick glance I'm not seeing a whole bunch of weird stuff going on. I have a similar setup going which you could look into. This is the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/PtrTn/ishetkutweerv4/blob/master/docker-compose-dev.yml) and this is the [dockerfile](https://github.com/PtrTn/ishetkutweerv4/blob/master/docker/development/php-fpm/Dockerfile) for php-fpm. Maybe that will give you a clue

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks on the speed of chocolate balls? Just curious.

Comment: @Cerad no need to downvote though. Anyway, I wouldn't need benchmarks. An initial request is about 4-6 seconds and then another 2-3 seconds for the profiler bar to load in. Seems a bit too much if you ask me. I got a native CentOS environment in a VM running sub 300ms on dev mode.

Answer (score 14):

If your bind mount is pointing to a folder on a Windows partition you will most likely get horrible performance. What I do is I clone the repo inside WSL in `~/dev` (where I put all my projects), then I run my containers from WSL's shell (I use Ubuntu 20.04). Then to be able to use my IDE (PhpStorm) and get the code in sync, I open the project from the `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\julien\dev\my-prohect\`. If you are using VS Code, there is an extension for that https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/09/03/wsl2.

I did create a mapped drive to make all of this even easier. In Windows' CMD:

`net use U: \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04 /PERSISTENT:YES`

Comment: This looks like a fair option. I'll give it a go! Loving the name of your containers though, looks like a weather related project? :p

Comment: @Julien B do you have a link to a setup like this? I use docker on windows (5 containers [node, php, nginx, redis, mysql]), I'm finding it incredibly slow 5s for a simple query (from front to back) of 5 records, and if it's in sequence, like 3, 4 queries the last one arrives a15s, the direct select in the bank (by the IDE) does not take 5ms. in postman I have the same result, ranging between 5 and 13s

Comment: This tips made my day!!!!!! 5000ms to 500ms per request! Thanks a lot!!!!